# quickblox push notification doesnt work in production mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I added quickblox to my app

In development mode, push notification system works well.

However, when i put my app in production mode, the backend system says the push was sent, but the push is not received.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [QBSettings setLogLevel:QBLogLevelDebug];
    [QBSettings setApplicationID:kAppID];
    [QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:kAuthorizationKey];
    [QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:kAuthorizationSecret];
    [QBSettings setAccountKey:@kAccountKey];

    [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:NO];

//switch to production mode 
#ifndef DEBUG
   [QBSettings setLogLevel:QBLogLevelNothing];
   [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES];
#endif


    return YES;
}
```

and then somewhere inside my app I have this code

```
-(void)sendPushMessage:(QBChatAbstractMessage *)absMessage toUser:(NSInteger)userId andDelegate:(NSObject<QBActionStatusDelegate>*)delegate{
    NSString *fullName = [self fullName];
    NSString *mesage;
    if(fullName){
    mesage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ says: %@",fullName, absMessage.text];
    }else {
        mesage = absMessage.text;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
    [aps setObject:mesage forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];

    [aps setObject:[self dictionaryRepresentation] forKey:@"user_info"];
    [payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

    NSLog(@"payload:%@",payload);
    QBMPushMessage *message = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];
    [QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:[@(userId) stringValue] delegate:delegate];
}
```

in development environment this code works very well.
I checked my production APNS certificate several times, deleted it, remade it, reinstalled it
and nothing is working in production mode

I tried sending myself a production push notification from the admin page

and received this 
[image]

and these are the users it was sent to

[image]
why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you test production pushes with AdHoc ipa builds?

If you test it with debug mode - it won't work

Read this topic [quickblox makes the same token for development and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234465/quickblox-makes-the-same-token-for-development-and-production)

I already wrote an answer how to make this work