# quickblox makes the same token for development and production

Tags: ios, quickblox

I added quickblox to my app,

And put up the development and production APNS certificates

when i open the app, in development mode, with the development flag off

```
[QBSettings setIsProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:NO]
```

i get a push notification token, sending messages to this token makes the arrive

, however, when I want to switch to production mode
i put

```
[QBSettings setIsProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES]
```

and then in the method `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken:`

gives the **EXACT** same development token.

How do I generate a production token instead? How to force a new token to be created?

Comment: As far as I know production tokens aren't generated until the app is signed by Apple and installed from the app store

Comment: so i cant test the app in production mode at all ?

Comment: No. Test is test and production is production - your app isn't in production until it is on the App Store

Comment: so how can i know that it will work in production mode ?

Comment: You also can test production by creating an ipa file and sign it with AdHoc provision profile

Comment: So, just use this line next way #ifndef DEBUG
    [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES];
#endif  . You don't need to switch it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to manage push zones manually

just add next lines as you can find in documentation http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios

```
#ifndef DEBUG 
   [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES]; 
#endif
```

What does they mean?

it means that with debug builds you will use dev environment.

With AdHoc or AppStore builds you will use prod environment.

So, you can create the AdHoc ipa file, sign it with AdHoc provision profile and it should work

Above 3 lines depend on next Xcode settings:
[image]

Comment: From latest SDK 2.2, above method is deprecated, once should use `[QBApplication sharedApplication].productionEnvironmentForPushesEnabled = YES;`

Comment: How can I add "production" environment with QuickBlox 2.7.1?